# String matches with prefixes

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am new to Javascript.
Suppose,I have a contact number and array of prefixes which are string.

```
contactNumber = "0204221246890";
prefixes = ["027", "020", "021", "022", "028", "029", "0204", "03", "04", "06", "07", "09"];
```

So the logic is I need to loop  through prefixes and

```
 if (contactNumber.startsWith(prefix)) {
         contactNumberPrefix = prefix
         contactNumberNumber = contactNumber.substring(lineNumberPrefix.length);

       }
```

How to best achieve this is through lodash or javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to loop through the available prefixes. It returns `true` if any one of the matches are `true`. See the demo below:

```js
let contactNumber = "0204221246890";
let prefixes = ["027", "020", "021", "022", "028", "029", "0204", "03", "04", "06", "07", "09"];

if (prefixes.some(prefix => contactNumber.startsWith(prefix))) {
  console.log('matches');
}
```

**Edit 1**:

If you need to return the matching prefix, its better to use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead. It returns the first matching item from the array.

```
let prefix = prefixes.find(prefix => contactNumber.startsWith(prefix));
return [contactNumber, prefix];
```

This will return the matching prefix and the contact number to the caller, which you can destructure.

Comment: So if the condition is true how can I return the contact number and prefix for further manipulation ?
Right now it says "prefix is not defined"

Comment: @pourushsinghgaur -- please see the edit on my question.